# Limit number of items from SharePoint/Outlook sync

Tags: outlook, office-integration, sync

I'd like to limit the number of items that a list can sync with Outlook, either with bandwidth or number of items. I have a relavitely large list and it ties our bandwidth up whenever someone new tries to connect to it using an Outlook sync.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've decided to solve this by implementing a expiration policy on older items that will get rid of the Outlook posts in the Outlook/SharePoint sync.

Comment: how to enable this policy? In which version of Sharepoint is it available? Can I configure this from Outlook?